# Generate request in SOAPUI with ArrayOfArrayOfString type

Tags: soapui

I have SOAP request like this. But I don't know how to generate request in in2 and in3 to array of array of string. Anyone know please give me an idea. Thanks

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rpc:imports soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="xsd:string">abcd</in0>
         <in1 xsi:type="xsd:long">1234</in1>
         <in2 xsi:type="rpc:ArrayOf_xsd_string" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[6]">
                <item>test1</item>
                <item>test2</item>
                <item>test3</item>
                <item>test4</item>
                <item>test5</item>
                <item>test6</item>
         </in2>
         <in3 xsi:type="rpc:ArrayOfArrayOf_xsd_string" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[][]">
         </in3>
      </rpc:imports>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I try with?